# What climbing plant can I grow on my balcony that's not poisonous to cats?

Tags: plant-recommendations, urban-gardening

I have a west-oriented balcony where I would like to grow a climbing plant, to separate my balcony from the neighborhood.

However, I found that most of the climbing plants like ivy are poisonous or at least a bit toxic for a cat. Another plant is [*Cissus alata*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cissus) but it's more for interiors: outdoor conditions in my [country](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krak%C3%B3w#Climate) (-10 to +20 Celsius degrees) might not be good for it.

Can you recommend any climbing plant for my place?

Comment: Maybe it's just my cat but I find she doesn't play or even rub up against poisonous plants, I have quite a lot of plants in and around my house.

Comment: @stemie I heard stories about cats that can differentiate and those that cannot. Any way to check where my cat belongs? Only way I can think of is to try with little toxic plant (e.g. causing only some little stomache aches).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an annual is OK, any of the climbing/pole beans - obviously you'd prefer a perennial from the other plants mentioned, but they can be decorative and fairly lush pretty quickly - as well as providing some food.

Hmm - a climbing rose might work. Non-toxic to cats, and there are certainly varieties that are hardy enough.

Hardy Kiwi has cats listed as a possible pest (evidently it's got some catnip-like scent) but I didn't see anything suggesting it was bad for the cats.